# How do I avoid functions to read escape characters?

Tags: python, pandas, escaping

I have a list string that depicts directory paths, e.g.:

```
| 'directory path' |
|:----------------:|
|'c:\\windows\\g\\subfolder1'|
|'c:\\windows\\g\\subfolder2'|
|'etc' |
```

The string is perfectly valid and when I print them they come out naturally as:

```
print(dir_list[0])
dir_list[0]

c:\windows\g\subfolder
Out[1]: 'c:\\windows\\g\\subfolder1'
```

However, when I use the string in a function I get the following error:

```
df['directory path'].str.contains(dir_list[0])
error: bad escape \g at position 10
```

Why do I get the error in the function when it works totally fine as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `regex=False` as [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) considers the pattern a regex by default:

```
df['directory path'].str.contains(dir_list[0], regex=False)
```

Or, if for some reason you need to keep the default `regex=True`, escape the characters:

```
import re
df['directory path'].str.contains(re.escape(dir_list[0]))
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: directory path, dtype: bool
```